# utilizing for loop while downloading data from server using function in R?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I am trying to download hourly streamflow data for the `Num_St` from our internal server using `function` `(i.e., myfunction)` and then store it in `tss` using `for loop`. When `i = 1` the `function` works but when `i = Num_St` `(i.e., data for multiple points)`, the `for loop` doesn't work. The `function` itself is too big to post here and i seems to struggle to create a `reproducible example` for this particular problem. I would appreciate any thoughts to how to store multiple points data in `tss`.

```
Num_st <- nrow(Stations)
for (i in 1:Num_st) {
  tss<- myfunction(id[i],Data[i],Stage[i])
  }
```

I tried below but its giving me error.

```
 tss[,i+1]<- myfunction(id[i],Data[i],Stage[i])
```

Comment: You can also try `out <- Map(myfunction, id, Data, Stage)` to get all of the data without an explicit `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to store the output in a list

```
tss <- vector('list', Num_st)
for (i in 1:Num_st) {
    tss[[i]]<- myfunction(id[i],Data[i],Stage[i])
  }
```